# Stored procedure does not return value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this problem. I have this query in which I used to model a stored procedure and I want to get the value in the column `clr_bal_amt`. I want it to return as a string from the database column.

However it does not return it. The query executes, but it does not get the value in that column.
The stored procedure looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindBranchVaultBalance
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
from dummy_table  
where bacid = ''1010000001'' and sol_id = ' + QUOTENAME(@sol_id, '''') + N' and
  acct_crncy_code = ' + QUOTENAME(@acct_crncy_code, '''') + N' and
  del_flg = ''N'' and acct_cls_flg = ''N''
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, N' + QUOTENAME(@query, '''') + N'  )
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

GO
```

I need some form of clarification. Why did this not return that value in that `clr_bal_amt` column?

*Edited*

The SQL is looking like this now

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindBranchVaultBalance]
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
from dummy_table  
where bacid = ''1010000001'' and sol_id = ' + QUOTENAME(@sol_id, '''') + N' and
  acct_crncy_code = ' + QUOTENAME(@acct_crncy_code, '''') + N' and
  del_flg = ''N'' and acct_cls_flg = ''N''
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, N' + REPLACE(@query, '''','''''') + N'  )
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Edits2**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindAFINACLEBranchVaultBalance]
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
from dummy_table
where bacid = ''1010000001'' and sol_id = ' + QUOTENAME(@sol_id, '''') + N' and
  acct_crncy_code = ' + QUOTENAME(@acct_crncy_code, '''') + N' and
  del_flg = ''N'' and acct_cls_flg = ''N''
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, N' + '... N''' + REPLACE(@query, '''','''''') + N''' ...'+ N'  )
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `QUOTENAME` accepts a `sysname` so `QUOTENAME(@query, '''')` is going to result is a large amount of truncation.

Comment: @Larnu, pls how do I return it

Comment: Don't use `QUOTENAME` on `@query`, use a different method to escape the characters (hint: `REPLACE`).

Comment: @Larnu, I am new to this Really. Can you assist with the source pls. Let me see what u mean

Comment: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu, U mean i should do, REPLACE(@query,''''') Correct?

Comment: No... Because that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Tells me 
incorrect syntax near 'N'
incorrect sytax near '1010000001'

Please See Edits

Comment: You've omitted the leading and trailing single quotes around `REPLACE` from my answer, @Keros ... `N'` <> `N'''`

Comment: @Larnu, Kindy show me Pls

Comment: *"show me plz"* It's *literally* in my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428249/2029983). In the above you haven't copied the leading and trailing single quotes (`'`). They are **needed**...

Comment: Now it shows Incorrect Syntax near 'N'

Comment: Why have you put the dots in there... The dots represent the *rest* of your code.

Comment: The code I gave you generates no syntax errors: [dB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ceb09cd544fd2d3781584fbd2269b8b)

Comment: Side note: the **easiest** way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` it. If you do this you'll quickly see the problems.

Comment: How Crazy I was. It works Now.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `OPENQUERY` rather than just querying the table directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned `QUOTENAME` accepts a `sysname` as a parameter (a synonym of `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`), and your variable `@query` is defined as an `nvarchar(MAX)`. As such if it's 129 or more characters long it'll be truncated; your value is clearly more than 128 characters.

Just use `REPLACE`:

```sql
N'... N''' + REPLACE(@query, '''','''''') + N''' ...'
```

As a bit of shameless self promotion, I explain this scenario more in-depth [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/an-in-depth-look-at-injecting/#literals).

---

To add emphasis on the OP's attempt to implement this, your attempt is not the same:

> ```sql
> N'... N' + REPLACE(@query, '''','''''') + N' ...'
> ```

Notice the lack of trailing and leading single quotes (`'`). The single quotes are **needed**. `REPLACE` *replaces* characters, it doesn't delimit identify them like `QUOTENAME` does.

Comment: tells me 
incorrect syntax near 'N'
incorrect sytax near '1010000001'

Did i miss something?

Comment: Then you've done something wrong, @Keros .

Comment: You missed the single quotes from my answer, @Keros ... Hence the syntax error, because it's not valid syntax.